# Crontab script su root / user -c does not execute

Tags: shell, cron, root

if been trouble-checking for hours and can't find out why my shell script won't execute properly when using a root crontab.

I'm on a vServer eqipped with

```
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
3.13.0-042stab113.11.
```

my script is a chmod 711 file:

```
/usr/local/sbin/bckup_script
```

and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S`
su - -c "chgrp postgres /backup/db"
su - -c "chmod 770 /backup/db"
su - -c "chown user /backup/db"
su - postgres -c "pg_dump db_name > /backup/db/${DATE}db_name.sql && pg_dumpall > /backup/db/${DATE}_all_db.out"
su - -c "rsync -a /home/user/value /backup/"
```

The crontab is started using

```
crontab -e
```

as

```
root
```

user

The crontab executes as far as I can tell from syslog.

When executed as root user (no crontab), the file will do what it's told to. Also my PATH is set properly and working.

I have no idea what am doing wrong.

---

Solution:
Thx to `Jay jargot` I found out what was wrong. To complete the question, here are the outputs you "asked" for:

crontab -l

```
#m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * bckup_script
```

Output of crontab was

```
/bin/sh: bckup_script: command not found
```

which lead me to the conclusion to use the absolute Path to the file which `solved` the problem.

my crontab -l now looks like follows and everything works like a charm!

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
49 20 * * 1-5 /usr/local/sbin/bckup_script
```

Thx very much!

Comment: Why are you using `su` in a script being run as root already?

Comment: Update the question with the result of `crontab -l`. Insert `set -x` in the second line of bckup_script. Modify the crontab and add `> /tmp/bckup_script.output 2>&1` at the end of the line. Wait the next execution and update the question with the content of /tmp/bckup_script.output.